# Finding certain rows and determining if they are negative or positive

Tags: r

I am trying to do something quite odd. I would like to somehow determine if the row of a separate data.frame is mostly negative or positive based on row numbers in a column of a different data.frame... I have included my example data frames (data.frame1 and data.frame2) and the desired output

```
>data.frame1
     col_a col_b  col_c
 1   1     1       1
 2   1    -1      -1 
 3   1     1       1 
 4  -1    -1      -1 
 5   1     1      -1

>data.frame2
   col_a
1    2
2    3
3    5


Example output/result 
     col_a     col_b
1      2     negative
2      3     positive
3      5     positive
```

Another example output could be

```
Example 2 output/result 
     col_a  col_b
1      2    -1
2      3     1
3      5     1
```

[image: Dataframe1]

[image: datafram2]
[image]
[image]

Thank you for all the answers.
Follow up to the first question: is there a way to get the output with the measurements from an ID column included? See example data frames and desired output below

```
 >data.frame1
       ID    col_a col_b  col_c
 1   Fish1   1     1       1
 2   Fish1   1    -1      -1 
 3   Fish1   1     1       1 
 4   Fish1  -1    -1      -1 
 5   Fish1   1     1      -1

>data.frame2
   col_a
1    2
2    3
3    5


Example output/result 
    ID   col_a     col_b
1  Fish1    2     -1
2  Fish1    3      1
3  Fish1    5      1
```

Comment: Read about *sign*: `sign(c(-11, 0, 11))`

Comment: could you give us an easy way to reproduce your problem by giving us the printout for `dput(data.frame1)` and `dput(data.frame2)`?

Comment: You can start with something like `rowSums(df1[df2$col_a,]) < 0` and bring it to your desired format

Answer (score 2):

Subset first dataframe rows based on second dataframe, then check the *sign*, then get the sum for the rows, then get *sign* again:

```
cbind(data.frame2,
      result = sign(rowSums(sign(data.frame1[ data.frame2$col_a, ]))))
#   col_a result
# 1     2     -1
# 2     3      1
# 3     5      1
```

---

**Note:** if the first dataframe has only values -1 and 1, then we can drop the inner *sign* step:

```
sign(rowSums(data.frame1[ data.frame2$col_a, ]))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution using `rowMeans` instead of `RowSums`.

```r
#making the example
df1 <- data.frame("a" = c(1,1,1,-1,1),
                  "b" = c(1,-1,1,-1,1),
                  "c"=  c(1,-1,1,-1,-1))

df2 <- data.frame("col_a" = c(2,3,5))

# Check if all indices of rows in d2 are in df1
stopifnot(all(df2$col_a %in% c(1:nrow(df1))))

# no second sign to get a logical value
df2$col_b <- rowMeans(sign(df1[df2$col_a,])) >= 0

# make to factor
df2$col_b <- ifelse(df2$col_b,"positive","negative")
```

Comment: Are we assuming 0 is negative? `sign(mean(c(-1, -1, 1, 1)))` vs `mean(c(-1, -1, 1, 1)) > 0`

Comment: `sign(0) == 0`, so therefore i cant say for sure how R sees it. I edited my answer to define 0 as positive.

Comment: Now we are assuming 0 is positive :) it is neither positive or negative. Anyway, nice use of rowMeans. Let's leave to OP to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `2` to `sign` of `rowMeans` and subset a labels vector.

Consider this data frame, where "neutral" outcomes are also possible.

```
d1
#   col_a col_b col_c col_d
# 1     1     1     1     1
# 2     1    -1    -1     1
# 3     1     1     1     1
# 4    -1    -1    -1    -1
# 5     1     1    -1     1
# 6     1    -1    -1    -1
```

In `d2` I use the complete subset for demonstration.

```
d2 |> 
  transform(res=c('negative', 'neutral', 'positive')[
    sign(rowMeans(d1[d2$col_a, ])) + 2])
#   col_a      res
# 1     1 positive
# 2     2  neutral
# 3     3 positive
# 4     4 negative
# 5     5 positive
# 6     6 negative
```

---

*Data:*

```
d1 <- structure(list(col_a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L), col_b = c(1L, 
-1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L), col_c = c(1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), 
    col_d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

d2 <- structure(list(col_a = 1:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```